# Flutter Authentication Flow with Gorouter and SharedPreferences

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, flutter-go-router

I want to create Authentication Flow with Gorouter and SharedPreferences. If the user is not logged in, it should go to `LoginScreen` else to `MainLayout` Screen. But in my case, `context.goNamed` does not work. There is no error show in my console

Here is the logic in my splash screen

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      checkLoginState();
    });
  }
  void checkLoginState() {
    print("in");
    if (locator.get<AppPreferences>().isLoggedIn()) {
      print("in questMainLayoutRoute");
      context.goNamed(AppRouteName.questMainLayoutRoute);
    } else {
      print("in loginScreen");
      context.goNamed(AppRouteName.loginScreen);
    }
  }
 

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
```

These are me routes'

```
abstract class AppRoute {
  static GoRouter routes = GoRouter(
    redirect: (context, state) => AppRouteName.splashScreen,
    routes: [
      GoRoute(
        name: AppRouteName.splashScreen,
        path: AppRouteName.splashScreen,
        builder: (context, state) => SplashScreen(),
      ),
     
      GoRoute(
        name: AppRouteName.loginScreen,
        path: AppRouteName.loginScreen,
        builder: (context, state) => LoginUI(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        name: AppRouteName.questMainLayoutRoute,
        path: AppRouteName.questMainLayoutRoute,
        builder: (context, state) => QuestMainLayout(),
      ),
}
```

Authentication Flow